# Replace nested double quotes with JavaScript RegEx

Tags: javascript, json, regex

I have a JSON-stringified object as follows. I need to parse the object using `JSON.parse`. I am facing nested double quotes which I want to replace with RegEx.

```
// input string 
var stringifyObj = '{
"a": "abcd"",
  "b": false,
  "c": [
    {
      "c": "1234",
      "d": "abcd",
      "e": [
        {
          "cs": "cs",
          "df": true
        }
      ],
      "g": "USE",
      "f": false,
      "g": "QA DCG",
      "h": "333 Market St",
      "i": "San Francisco",
      "j": " 94568"
    },
    {
      "k": "20570",
      "l": "test",
      "m": [
        {
          "n": "USD",
          "o": true
        }
      ],
      "p": "US",
      "q": true,
      "r": "Wires_defect 13205 testing",
      "s": "333 market street_retesting 13205",
      "t": "SF_test",
      "u": "ABCD"",
      "v": false
    }
  ]
}';
```

How can I parse this stringify object "a and u" properties contains nested double quotes.

I tried to replace but did not work : `replace(/(".*?"):(".*?)"(.*?")/g,"$1:$2\\\"$3")`

Comment: That's not a stringified object, then. Where is this broken JSON coming from?

Comment: what have you tried until now? what is your expression? btw. the expected out put cant be correct `...\"'@...` seems wrong should it not be `...\"@...`

Comment: @winner_joiner I edited plz check

Comment: Down voters: Need any clarity?

Comment: @venkat7668 i have updated my answer., please check.

Answer (score 0):

depends on the values expected in the String, how many quotes, special char, and so on ...

but for this special case you could use this, or at least use it as starting point

```js
var bad_json_string = '{"a":"abc"@#"}';
var cleaned_string = bad_json_string.replace(/([^:]+:")(.*)"(.*"})/g, function(){return RegExp.$1 + RegExp.$2 +"'"+ RegExp.$3 });

document.write(cleaned_string);
//    tested on Win7 with chrome 44+
```

**Update 1:**

The updated json is not easy fixed with javascript RegExp Expression. With nested List/Objects/...

I would suggest cleaning up the Json from the server, if that is not possible than I would write a function to "parse" the string in an other manner.

**Update 2:**

A possible Function-Solution could/should be this(*just quick demo, review/**optimize** for production usage*)

```js
var bad_json_string = '{\r\n"a": "abcd"",\r\n  "b": false,\r\n  "c": [\r\n    {\r\n      "c": "1234",\r\n      "d": "abcd",\r\n      "e": [\r\n        {\r\n          "cs": "cs",\r\n          "df": true\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      "g": "USE",\r\n      "f": false,\r\n      "g": "QA DCG",\r\n      "h": "333 Market St",\r\n      "i": "San Francisco",\r\n      "j": " 94568"\r\n    },\r\n    {\r\n      "k": "20570",\r\n      "l": "test",\r\n      "m": [\r\n        {\r\n          "n": "USD",\r\n          "o": true\r\n        }\r\n      ],\r\n      "p": "US",\r\n      "q": true,\r\n      "r": "Wires_defect 13205 testing",\r\n      "s": "333 market street_retesting 13205",\r\n      "t": "SF_test",\r\n      "u": "ABCD"",\r\n      "v": false\r\n    }\r\n  ]\r\n}';

var t = bad_json_string.match(/^(.| )*$/gm);

function unQuote(string){
 return string.replace(/^"/,"").replace(/"$/,"");
}

function trim(string, chr){
 return string.replace(new RegExp("^(" + (chr || " " )+")*"),"").replace(new RegExp( "(" + (chr || " ") + ")*$"),"");
}

var clean = "";

function buildObj(list, idx){

 if(list.length<=idx)
  return;
  
    var item = trim(list[idx]);
 
 switch(item){
  case "{":
  case "[":
  case "}":
  case "]":
  case "},":
  case "],":
   clean += item;
   break;
  case "":
   break; 
  default: 
   var line = item.split(":");
   var index = unQuote(line[0]);
   var value = trim(trim(line[1]),",");
   clean += index + ":";
   
   if(value.indexOf("\"")==0){
    clean += "'"+ unQuote(value) + "',";
   }
   else if(value.indexOf("{")==0 || value.indexOf("[")==0){
    clean += value;
   }
   else{
    clean += value + ",";
   }
   
 }

 buildObj(list, ++idx);
}


buildObj( t, 0);

document.write(clean);
// to get the object you could do this, but dont forget eval==evil. :)
 var t;
 eval("t="+clean);
 document.write("<br/><br/><br/>");
 document.write("Object prop 'a' => " + t['a']);
// tested on Win7 with Chrome 44+
```

Comment: @venkat7668 did you try the function version?